# Need to figure out the random number the function gives me

Tags: python

Since I am using random generator to place the ships how can I be able to get the exact value of x and y coordinate from my function:

```
def addShip(board):
    x = randint(0, 9)
    y = randint(0, 9)
board[x][y] = 1
```

How would i be able to print the exact value that the function used for x and y? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: ...`return` them from it?

Comment: those are local variables in the function. when the function returns, those variables are destroyed. since you never USE them (e.g. return them, store them elsewhere), the function's effectively useless.

Comment: ``return x, y``? This what you are looking for??

Comment: Why is the function called `addShip` when it doesn't add a ship?

Answer (score 0):

```
def addShip(board):
    x = randint(0, 9)
    y = randint(0, 9)
    return x, y

board[x][y] = 1
```